# How to use alert if the system date is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I use alert if the date of system is changed in `javascript`. The date can be change manually of automatically. 
[Thought is, Mainly client want to get an notification after day of end and start of the day. Total sales of today will be notified to the client when tomorrow is starting. like if the date of 30 and when it will be 31 and mail will be send to the client that you have sold sum quantity yesterday or date of 30]
Here I have tried this code. I am new in `javascript` so suggestion is needed.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

$("#today").change(function () {
    alert(today);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `system date is changed` ? did you mean client's machine date?

Comment: yes it may be my PC or client's PC.

Comment: You can't the browser have only one date.

Comment: What do you mean by "changed"? be more specific, changed from what point to what point?

Comment: You mean if someone actually changes the time on the computer from when you originally read it? Or if they change a textbox value?

Comment: My purpose is to send a request to controller if the date is changed manually or automatically.

Comment: @CodeGodie, OP would like to have some JS function, that should be called whenever machine's date is changed, and I guess that's not at all possible.

Comment: @AbdulHamid, machine's date will be changed on every milliseconds, then how many calls will you make, :D ? Instead, put some more details on what you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: Pass the date from the server, instead of requesting it from the client browser. Then it will not be an issue.

Comment: @MokshShah My client want to get an email for total sales of the day. if day is Sunday and date is 29 he wants to know that what is the total sale of the Sunday when it is already Monday. An email will be sent automatically if the day is Monday or the date is 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot listen to the event like you a trying, the only way you can do this is with a synthetic event that is fired when the date changes:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

var changedate = function(date, to){
    date = to;
    document.trigger('dateChange');
}

document.on('dateChange', function () {
    alert(today);
});
```

Comment: I am changing date of my PC but it is not firing.